# Can you efficiently remove any k elements from a map without iterating?

Tags: java, dictionary, performance

I have a map I've populated (say it's a HashMap). I want it cut down to size... I don't care which elements I remove, I just want k of the elements removed.

What's the most efficient way to do this (other than iterating)?

**Edit:** k is not known in advance. Suggestions to based on other kinds of maps are relevant.

Comment: i don't think  so this is possible without iterating in `HashMap`.

Comment: From the public API provided by the `HashMap`, I think there is no better way than iterating `k` times. If this were your own chained hashtable, you can cut off some entry chains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic hashmap has only a limited number of interface functions.  If K is small, I don't see any obvious better way than iterating, and breaking out of the iteration once K keys are removed.  Of course, if K is large it might be better to do something else, such as preserve size-k elements and clear.   If you need particular characteristics, your own hashmap could have whatever characteristics you need.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "preserve size-k elements"? Do you mean, having the map hold k-element tuples as its value?

Comment: for example, if you were intending to cut down to 1 element, it would be more effecient to remember that one, clear the map, then reinsert that one.  Or for a small residual size in general, to make a copy of the map containing only the desired number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

If its HashMap, i don't think there is a better option than iterating, but if you can use TreeMap use this...

`map.headMap(key).clear();`

**Eg:**

```
 public class Test     
    {     
        public static void main( String[] args )     
        {     
            SortedMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();     
            map.put( 1, "HI" );     
            map.put( 2, "BYE" );     
            map.put( 4, "GUY" );     
            map.put( 7, "SKY" );     
            map.put( 9, "HELLO" );     

            System.out.println(map.keySet());  

            map.headMap(5).clear(); // 5 is exclusive  

            System.out.println(map.keySet());  
        }     
    }
```

Comment: That means I'd either need a numeric key or keep track of the order of insertion... doesn't it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is no more efficient than my suggestion - `clear()` will iterate through the entry set of the view, calling `remove()`. It's just a far-more-indirected way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not iterate? You can remove *from the iterator* which is likely to be very efficient - no extra lookup required:

```
Iterator<Map.Enty<Foo, Bar>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < k && it.hasNext; i++)
{
    it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

Comment: Why not iterate? Because that's Omega(k) time at best, and since I don't care which elements I remove, I might be able to do better.

Comment: @eyalroz: I don't believe so. Think of it this way: the array underlying the map contains references to everything. You need `k` of those references to be cleared - so how could it possibly be less than O(k) time? The only situation in which I could see you doing better would be if `k > n/2` (for map size n) in which case you could be better off starting from scratch and *keeping* n-k elements. Do you have evidence that in your situation this is actually causing a bottleneck?

Comment: Well, if there had been some way to mark elements as unused... but I guess with just a HashMap (regardless of whether you use the API or the internals) it's probably impossible.

Comment: @eyalroz even if you 'marked them as unused' you would still need to do O(k) operations. Remember that O(k) is not O(n) and for this function it must be Ω(k) unless you roll your own data structure. The shortest distance between two points is the shortest distance you must walk.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating is the only way.

```
// this is the number of items you want to remove
final int NUMBER_TO_REMOVE = 2;

// this is your map
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("a", "1");
map.put("b", "2");
map.put("c", "3");
map.put("d", "4");
map.put("e", "5");
map.put("f", "6");
map.put("g", "7");
map.put("h", "8");
map.put("i", "9");

// get the keys
String[] keys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);

// remove the correct number from the map
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_TO_REMOVE; i++) {
    map.remove(keys[i]);
}

// your map is now NUMBER_TO_REMOVE elements smaller
```